# Gradle task to publish / upload android apk to Http Server

Tags: android, jenkins, upload, gradle, publish

So far we used Jenkins with Ant to build our Android APKs. The built APK, the proguard mappings.txt and some release notes get uploaded to a Http Server using curl

```
curl -k -F "app=@$apk_dir" -F "release_notes=@$release_notes_file" "https://ourserver.com/apps/internal/app/$app_dir/$version"
```

whereas app dir is assembled by some parameters from the Android Manifest

```
app_dir="${app_name}-${some_other_manifest_meta_data}"
```

As I now start switching to Gradle I want to move this to the gradle build file.
I thought of a task that depends on the Android plugin assemble task and uploads the assembled apk, the release notes and the proguard file onto the Http Server.

Unfortunately the official Gradle doc and most links just describe how to upload to Maven or Ivy servers.

Would be great if someone could provide me code or at least hints on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way to port your upload task to Gradle would be to use [an `Exec` task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

Your task might end up looking something like this:

```
task upload(type:Exec) {
    executable "/bin/sh"
    args "-c", "curl -k -F [...]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, even though I thought of an more Gradle / Groovy based solution this one works!