# How to upload multiple files by Gradle

Tags: gradle, upload

Can you suggest task which will upload multiple files to remote WebDav server?

I could achieve it with the following script. It has only one problem - it adds version to filename

```
version = "1.0"

configurations {
    myConfig
}

artifacts{
    //files is a directory where upload files are placed
    for (def f : file("files").listFiles()) {
        myConfig f
    }
}

task publish(type: Upload) {
    configuration = configurations.myConfig

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "WEB_DAV_URL_HERE"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sure, why not. If it can be done in groovy, it can be done in gradle. if it can be done in java code or a command line utility, it can be invoked from gradle.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible by gradle. How?

Comment: Can you give some details about how you do this currently outside gradle? Then I can point you to how to achieve the same thing within gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle can directly call bash, Tanis.7x has answer this kind of problem：

```
task upload(type:Exec) {
      executable "/bin/sh"
      args "-c", "curl -k -F [...]"
   }
}
```

[Gradle task to publish / upload android apk to Http Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965633/gradle-task-to-publish-upload-android-apk-to-http-server)

You need little modify to upload multiple files.

Then change to `how to upload file to server by curl`, you can fix it~

Comment: I think it should be possible to upload file by gradle only (without bash)